# Parsing fields from html with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

Im trying to parse an html output from a url call but i found myself struggling on how i could get it working.

Im using the following code:

```
    import urllib2
    import base64 as b64
    import lxml.html as LH

    request = urllib2.Request('http://%s%s' % (fInput[1], fInput[2]))
    base64string = b64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (fInput[3], fInput[4])).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    html = response.read()
    root = LH.fromstring(html)
    sibling_content = lambda x: [b.getparent().getnext().text_content() for b in root.cssselect("td b:contains('{0}')".format(x))]
    fields = ['groupList','namelist']


    for result in zip(*[sibling_content(field) for field in fields]):
        print result
```

The result i have when i print the output is:

```
('Admins', '\nme\nmyself\nirene')('guests', '\nhin\nhinself\nbacon')
```

The output that would fit for what i need is have an array like this, so i could insert it into a database:

```
['Admins', 'me','myself','nirene'],['guests', 'hin','hinself','bacon']
```

FOllowing, im sending the Html returned by the HTTP request:

```
<BODY bgcolor="#dddddd">
   <TABLE bgcolor="#dddddd" border="1">
      <TR>
         <TD valign="top"><B>MainList</B></TD>
         <TD>
            <TABLE>
               <TR>
                  <TD>
                     <TABLE bgcolor="#dddddd" border="1">
                        <TR>
                           <TD valign="top"><B>groupList</B></TD>
                           <TD>Admins</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                           <TD valign="top"><B>namelist</B></TD>
                           <TD>
                              <TABLE>
                                 <TR>
                                    <TD>me</TD>
                                 </TR>
                                 <TR>
                                    <TD>myself</TD>
                                 </TR>
                                 <TR>
                                    <TD>irene</TD>
                                 </TR>
                              </TABLE>
                           </TD>
                        </TR>
                     </TABLE>
                     <TABLE bgcolor="#dddddd" border="1">
                        <TR>
                           <TD valign="top"><B>groupList</B></TD>
                           <TD>guests</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                           <TD valign="top"><B>namelist</B></TD>
                           <TD>
                              <TABLE>
                                 <TR>
                                    <TD>hin</TD>
                                 </TR>
                                 <TR>
                                    <TD>hinself</TD>
                                 </TR>
                                 <TR>
                                    <TD>bacon</TD>
                                 </TR>
                              </TABLE>
                           </TD>
                        </TR>
                     </TABLE>
                  </TD>
               </TR>
            </TABLE>
         </TD>
      </TR>
   </TABLE>
</BODY>
```

Any ideas of how i could get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `hin`, `hinself`, `bacon` elements in your expected output aren't found anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: Editing it to add, my bad on copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xpath`:

```
root=LH.fromstring(html)
[t.xpath('.//td[not(contains(.,"\n"))]/text()')
    for t in root.xpath('.//table[@bgcolor="#dddddd"]')]
```

*out:*

```
[['Admins', 'me', 'myself', 'irene'], ['guests', 'hin', 'hinself', 'bacon']]
```

Comment: @Thales -- :) if you often need to extract data from html/xml, xpath is a really nice tool to have.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little confused by your question. Are you just asking how to turn

```
('Members', '\nme\nmyself\nirene')('Members_2', '\nhin\nhinself\nbacon')
```

into

```
['Members', 'me','myself','nirene'],['Members_2', 'hin','hinself','bacon']
```

That's easy:

```
>>> x = [('Members', '\nme\nmyself\nirene'), ('Members_2', '\nhin\nhinself\nbacon')]
>>> [[y[0]] + y[1].splitlines()[1:] for y in x]
```

---

FYI you should take a look at the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) Python module. Instead of all the `urllib2` digest cruft it lets you just write

```
requests.get(url, auth=(user, pass))
```

Comment: Hi, I will update the question propertly, but what im seeking is to transform the output into an array. So i could use the data to insert into a db

Comment: and in what sense does this not answer your question

Comment: i w as out to get coffee :)

Well, could you please give an example how i could apply it into the script?

i did : x =package ( breaks to new line )
print [[y[0]] + y[1].splitlines()[1:] for y in x] and the output was
-1
[['\n']]
[['\n']]

Comment: @Thales try to figure it out =) You've already constructed `zip(*[sibling_content(field) for field in fields])`. Call that `x`. Then `print x` and look at what it is.

Comment: Im voting your reply. lazyness should be not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

I think just stripping the whitespace from the text content should work. So in your code you could add a strip call to this line:

sibling_content = lambda x: [b.getparent().getnext().text_content()**.strip()** for b in root.cssselect("td b:contains('{0}')".format(x))]